# Login - Allow only 3 attempts

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a new application..I created a login page successfully..Now I need to modify the login page ..Only 3 attempts only allowed for a user ..If the user wrongly enters the password more than 3 times(within 5 min) his account must be blocked..And error message must be shown as You cant access your page ..Please share your ideas...

Comment: How are you storing the user information?

Answer (score 10):

use a MembershipProvider and in your web.config, in system.web you can configure number of attempts and timeouts. Set maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" and passwordAttemptWindow="5" for your requirements.

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider"
         type="MyMembershipProvider"
         autogenerateschema="true"
         connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="8"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
         passwordAttemptWindow="5"
         passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
         applicationName="/"  />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

This will require some configuration, but when configured properly (maybe even with a roleprovider) the default asp.net Login Controls can handle almost everything for you, even a PasswordRecovery and CreateUserWizard. The MembershipProvider will generate all required tables for user registration automatically.

The database can be a mdb file, ms sqlserver or mysql database.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add an int-column to the user-table called `FailedLogins`. Count it up everytime it he fails and if the counter is bigger then 3 don't allow any logins anymore from that account.

**Edit:** If you want to reset the tries after a certain amount of time, you'll have to add a datetime-column (f.e. `LastFailedLogin`) and check if enough time has passed to allow further attempts and/or reset the counter.

Comment: Tnx for the reply... If today I logged in 2 times and got failure.. next day If i entered wrongly count will allow only one time am i right..

Comment: @Jafry: That depends...when do you want to reset it? If you want to reset it after a certain amount of time, you'll have to add a field which holds the date/time of the last failed login, and reset it if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use the *Membership.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts* property to track the login attempts.

There is a working code example of displaying error messages here:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1520434/3652047.aspx

Comment: Perhaps this link might help: http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/validating-user-credentials-against-the-membership-user-store-cs

Comment: Tnx for the reply ..I got some ideas about manual login process.. But still i am not clear ..CAn u help me

Answer (score 2):

How many users are we talking, here? 1? Hundreds?

If there is just one, you could create a static int variable and static DateTime variable. When the program is started, set the int nTries to 0 and DateTime staticDate to Now.

Each time you show the login screen, check that nTries < MAX_TRIES and timeSpan < 5 minutes. If timeSpan is greater than 5 minutes, set nTries to 0 and update staticDate to Now.

If you like reading/writing with text files, you could also easily read/write the number of tries to/from a text file. In that case, you could have one line for each user, if you have a small application with just a few users (avoid the database overhead).

If you have hundreds of users, you'll want to use a database. In that database, you can store each user, his last login attempt time stamp, and the number of tries he has had.

Comment: Text file is actually a really really bad idea, cause it only works as long as the user doesn't simply open the file and change it.  Users are notoriously tricky, stupid, scary people. If they are given even the slightest chance, they will take it and amaze you :P

Comment: I agree. My answer was based on whether the OP just wanted to test something in the absence of any other storage mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for that,

```
//if login failed
if (session["loginclient"] != null)
{
     if(Convert.ToInt32(session["loginclient"] ) == 3)
          Response.Redirect("Forgetpassword.aspx")
     else
          session["loginclient"] = Convert.ToInt32(session["loginclient"] ) + 1
}
else
{
    session["loginclient"] = 1;
}
```