# How to block a user after a specified failed attempts and unblocking the user after 5 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, login-attempts

I would like to ask how do I block a user after a specified failed attempts. After 30 minutes or whatever time, the user will be able to log in again.. Here's my sample code for log in.

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SimplerAES AES = new SimplerAES();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();
    }
    protected void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtUsername.Text == "" || txtPassword.Text == "")
        {
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
            txtUsername.Text = "";
            txtPassword.Text = "";
            lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Username/Password";
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SeiboLMS.Helper.GetConnectionString());
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName=@UserName";

            com.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            com.Parameters[0].Value = txtUsername.Text;

            SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();

            if (data != null)
            {
                while (data.Read())
                {
                    if (txtPassword.Text == AES.Decrypt(data["Password"].ToString()))
                    {
                        if (data["UserTypeID"].ToString() == "1")
                        {
                            Session["userid"] = data["UserID"].ToString();
                            Session["usertypeid"] = data["UserTypeID"].ToString();
                            Session["username"] = data["UserName"].ToString();
                            Session["password"] = data["Password"].ToString();
                            Helper.Logs(int.Parse(data["UserID"].ToString()), 1, "Log In Successful");
                            Response.Redirect("Admin/Default.aspx");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Session["userid"] = data["UserID"].ToString();
                            Session["usertypeid"] = data["UserTypeID"].ToString();
                            Session["username"] = data["UserName"].ToString();
                            Session["password"] = data["Password"].ToString();
                            Helper.Logs(int.Parse(data["UserID"].ToString()), 1, "Log In Successful");
                            Response.Redirect("Employees/Default.aspx");
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Username/Password.";
                        txtUsername.Text = "";
                        txtPassword.Text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Username/Password.";
                txtUsername.Text = "";
                txtPassword.Text = "";
            }

            data.Close();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Please share with me what ideas do you have there. 
Thank you in advance..

Comment: Let the slightly off-topic "why aren't you hashing your passwords" firestorm ensue...

Comment: Well, a simple solutions would be to add a timestamp column in your DB table. So, when a user logs in you can do a simple check to see if the current time exceeds the timestamp byt 5 mins or more. And same, if a user fails to log on 5 times you simply add a new timestamp. Not sure if this is the best way to go about, but it should be simple enough.

Comment: Also off-topic: learn about `using`. It will help you get hired :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Login - Allow only 3 attempts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988013/login-allow-only-3-attempts)

Answer (score 3):

This question has been answered many times.

Search for [c# login with failed attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+login+with+failed+attempts&submit=search)

This particular question is very similar.
[Login - Allow only 3 attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988013/login-allow-only-3-attempts)

The [top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3988168/444610) by [Willem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245581/willem) has the following text:

> use a MembershipProvider and in your web.config, in system.web you can
>   configure number of attempts and timeouts. Set
>   maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" and passwordAttemptWindow="5" for your
>   requirements.

I suggest that if you find this helpful, you go vote up Willems [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3988168/444610).

Comment: When you find a question that is an exact duplicate you should vote to close, or post a comment with a link, rather than re-posting answers to exact duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MembershipProvider or depending on your database structure, create your own.  Lots of ways to accomplish this, but one way is to include  login_attempt, lockflag and timestamp  columns.  I'm guessing you have the login_attempt counter and are incrementing this (and resetting it to zero when successful)   Then at login you check the values and if the user is locked check the timestamp to see when and if enough time has lapsed for the account to be unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you could do is the following:

1) Add in your users table, a field (DateTime) indicating the time that he/she was blocked by exceeds the maximum login attempts.
2) Add a key in the web.config (AppSettings, perhaps) that indicate how long users that had  access blocked must wait until they can try again.
3) When trying to authenticate the user, check if the lock field (DateTime) is null, if it is the user performs the login normally. Otherwise compare the current time with the time it is in this field from the table, if greater than the appsettings value, prevents the user to login.

Hope I helped!